# Cordova Multiple dex build when using admob-pro and wizcorp/facebook connect

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

i'm having the following issue on building an Android Cordova.

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
```

The problem only happens when i use [Wizcorp/Facebook](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) with [AdMob-Pro](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro).

Comment: Hi @bobsouza Did you solve it? Thanks!!

Comment: @chemitaxis not yet. we've created another app using other plugins. this way i got the "problem solved"

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude android-support-v4.jar that got included by Wizcorp Facebook plugin. Trick is simple you need to create build-extras.gradle inside platforms/android and add following:

```
configurations {
   all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

the solution is in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32143042/1678851), but doesn't work in my case.
@mladen5 solution, not mine.