# Error: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotations/AnimRes with Admob and Facebook Cordova plugins

Tags: android, cordova, jar, ionic-framework

I'm building an app using cordova and the Ionic framework.

- I'm using the Wizcorp facebook plugin:
  https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin .
- and I recently added the google admob plugin:
  https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro

However now when I build my project I'm met with the error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotations/AnimRes;
```

Other SO solutions mention multiple `android-support-v4.jar` files conflicting, however the only `android-support-v4.jar` file I can find is within the facebook plugin.

Another solution mentioned conflicting versions (i.e `android-support-v4.jar` conflicting with `android-support-v13.jar`) - again, I cannot see any references to `android-support-v13.jar` within my project.

Another solution was conflicting `android-support-annotations.jar` and `android-support-v4.jar`: [multiple dex files define landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342444/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-annotation-animres) . I cannot find any `android-support-annotations.jar` files within my project, except something that is created in: `myProject\platforms\android\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug`
[image]

However I don't understand how this is getting created.

How can I solve this problem? The problem can be easily reproduced:

```
>ionic start myApp tabs
>cd myApp
>cordova plugin add https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"
>cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admobpro
>ionic platform android
>ionic build android
```

(where APP_ID and APP_NAME are the ID and name of a facebook application)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to exclude android-support-v4.jar that got included by Wizcorp Facebook plugin. Trick is simple you need to create `build-extras.gradle` inside platforms/android and add following:

`configurations {
   all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}`

And that's it, now every plugin that uses android support lib will work with this FB plugin.
You could probably put this somewhere in default build.gradle but i couldn't figure out exactly where, this build-extras file get auto included so its fine.

Comment: Thanks man! I used your solution from the github issue post (same as this) the other day and everything seems to be working great now!

Comment: I tried several solutions, in vain. but the only one works is this. Thanks.

Comment: awesome!! made my day :)

Comment: The admob plugin at https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova solves this problem as it uses gradle dependencies the plugin itself

Answer (score 0):

You should try to clean your project by using `cordova clean`.

In my case it works.